# WordPress elementor icons (SVG) display different than expected

Tags: html, css, svg

I get strange behavior when I try to insert icons to my elementor page design **in SVG format.**

This is the original design (supplied with zeplin.io) which im trying to implement with elementor
[image]

before I add the last icon, the result in elementor is:

[image]

You can see that only the first icon display as expected

Which is strange, but even more strange is that when I had the last I con I get this:

[image]

Now non of the icon display as expected, although some of then are more similar to the expected result.

The heart icon got flipped, and the colors changed for the other icons,

- Why would adding a new icon effect other icons in such a way?
- Why the color and the icon direction doesn't display as set by the SVG design?
- NOTE, the direction might be RTL related, but why only the heart got flipped?

I know that I could easily solve this issue by changing the format to PNG, but I could like to understand the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Do the icons have duplicate id values i.e. does one icon have an element with id="XX" and another icon have the same id="XX" on one of its elements? All id values must be unique on a page.

Comment: Yes, it was something of this sort - see the full answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is happens because the icons have duplicate class values, i.e. the svg is added as-is to the dom tree, along with the `<style>` definitions.

Therefore any class or id that is duplicated in two SVGs will collide, and the solution is

- open the svg with any text editor
- search/replace all id/class defined in `<style>` to have unique name

NOTE: the reason it doesn't happen in the orginial design is that there, the SVGs are added with `img` tag.

Woprdpress doesn't allow uploading SVGs as images for security reason (I have no idea what kind of security issue it can create, but this is a question by itself)

EDIT: I just noticed that once you add an SVG as an icon, it also become available as an image, so it might be a better solution to upload the SVG as icon and then use them as images. but I didn't try it.